# Inverse of a function 2

Tags: calculus

What is the inverse of the function $f(x)=x+3[2x]+2[3x]$?
The function is one by one and has an inverse.

Comment: Why do you expect the inverse to have a nice closed form (if the inverse even exists in the first place)? What even is the domain and range of your function? The entire real line?  What makes you think the function is even going to be invertible in the first place?

Comment: Consider the following: each of the pieces that make up your function are monotonically increasing so it follows that your function is too. What is the limit as x approaches 1/3 from the left? From the right?

Comment: What is the definition of the [x] function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

$$  f(x)=x+3\lfloor2x\rfloor+2\lfloor3x\rfloor $$

Since

$$ x=\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)+ \lfloor x \rfloor$$

we have

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&x-\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor\\
&&+3\lfloor2\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor+ \lfloor x \rfloor\right)\rfloor+2\lfloor3\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor+ \lfloor x \rfloor\right)\rfloor\\
&=&x-\lfloor x \rfloor+3\lfloor2\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\rfloor+2\lfloor3\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\rfloor\\
&&+\lfloor x \rfloor+6\lfloor x \rfloor+6\lfloor x \rfloor\\
&=&f\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)+13\lfloor x \rfloor
\end{eqnarray}

On the interval $[0,1)$, the function $f$ can be defined piecewise as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & 0\le x<\frac{1}{3}\\x+2&\frac{1}{3}\le x<\frac{1}{2}\\x+5&\frac{1}{2}\le x<\frac{2}{3}\\x+7&\frac{2}{3}\le x<1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Combining with equation (1) we get

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&f\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)+13\lfloor x \rfloor\\
&=&+13\lfloor x \rfloor+\begin{cases}
x-\lfloor x \rfloor & 0\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{1}{3}\\x-\lfloor x \rfloor+2&\frac{1}{3}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{1}{2}\\x-\lfloor x \rfloor+5&\frac{1}{2}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{2}{3}\\x-\lfloor x \rfloor+7&\frac{2}{3}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<1\end{cases}\\
&=&\begin{cases}
x+12\lfloor x \rfloor & 0\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{1}{3}\\x+12\lfloor x \rfloor+2&\frac{1}{3}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{1}{2}\\x+12\lfloor x \rfloor+5&\frac{1}{2}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<\frac{2}{3}\\x+12\lfloor x \rfloor+7&\frac{2}{3}\le x-\lfloor x \rfloor<1\end{cases}\\
\end{eqnarray}

So for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we may define $f$ on the interval $[n,n+1)$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+12n &  n+0\le x<n+\frac{1}{3}\\
x+12n+2&n+\frac{1}{3}\le x<n+\frac{1}{2}\\
x+12n+5&n+\frac{1}{2}\le x<n+\frac{2}{3}\\
x+12n+7&n+\frac{2}{3}\le x<n+1\end{cases}
\end{equation}

So the graph of the function consists of collection of straight line segments of slope 1. Each segment can be easily inverted.

Let us invert the first segment:

\begin{eqnarray}
y=x+12n&\text{ for }&n\le x<n+\frac{1}{3}\\
x=y+12n&\text{ for }&n\le y<n+\frac{1}{3}\\
y=x-12n&\text{ for }&n\le y<n+\frac{1}{3}\\
y=x-12n&\text{ for }&13n\le x<13n+\frac{1}{3}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Applying the same process to each of the four parts give the inverse function.

For each integer $n$ and for each $x$ in the specified interval, $f^{-1}(x)$ is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}
x-12n&\text{ for }13n+0\le x<13n+\frac{1}{3}\\
x-12n-2&\text{ for }13n+\frac{7}{3}\le x<13n+\frac{5}{2}\\
x-12n-5&\text{ for }13n+\frac{11}{2}\le x<13n+\frac{17}{3}\\
x-12n-7&\text{ for }13n+\frac{23}{3}\le x<13n+8
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Note that the domain of the inverse is a collection of disjoint intervals.